# Get fb user's gender via php

Tags: php, facebook

I have got an frame app on Facebook.
Now i need to get user's gender with php.
I have got the following code to get the user's id, how should i modify it to get gender?

```
$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), TRUE);
echo $data["user_id"];
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `$data` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$facebook->api('/me/friends', array('fields' => 'id,name,gender'));
```

This gives you the id,name, and gender of your friends